# addSubview doesn't work in UIView - Swift Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints, addsubview

I need to add a UIButton as a subview on a UIView but it actually doesn't appear at runtime.
This is my code:

```
let moreButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "more"), for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    addSubview(moreButton)
    moreButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    moreButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    moreButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    moreButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    
    
}
```

The button isn't added eventually to the view. I'm sure this is an easy fix but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you the viewController is showing anything since you're doing it without storyboards, check out this simple tutorial:

> https://medium.com/better-programming/creating-a-project-without-storyboard-in-2020-and-without-swifui-82080eb6d13b

If the problem is with that UIButton, try to set up the subviews in viewDidLoad:

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

let cardView = CardView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.addSubview(cardView)
    
    /// Constraints
    let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    cardView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    cardView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    cardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true
    cardView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    cardView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
}

}

final class CardView: UIView {

let moreButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Button title", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    self.addSubview(moreButton)
    
    /// Constraints
    let margins = self.layoutMarginsGuide
    moreButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    moreButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    moreButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true
    moreButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    moreButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
}
}
```

I've set up margins for the constraints and also added a leadingAnchor constraint, that might have been the issue as well.

Comment: The problem is that cardView is not a viewController but a UIView so the only way I can initialize the button is in the init

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. I've updated the snippet to see how it'll work with a custom UIView. The problem could've also been translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints for the cardView or setting up additional constraints for the UIView. I've copied the constraints, but they can probably be set up better